# How to align 2 divs parallel to each other

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to align to divs parallel from each other, but it is not lining up properly.

I have already tried a number of the solutions posted on the site, but none of them are working.

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue would be appreciated.

```
    <section class="section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10">
                    <div class="content">
                      <div class="wrapper">
                      <p class="content-media left">    
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/" alt="">

        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <div class="float:right;width:45%;">
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum <em>Lorem</em>, Lorem impsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</em>.</p>

    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</section>  





body {
    font-family: georgia, "times new roman", times, serif
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
}

.container p, 
.container div img {
    display: inline-block;
}

.container p {
    width: 60%;
    float: right;
}

.container div img {
    width: 38%;
    float: right;
}

.logo {
  position:fixed;
  bottom: 25px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100px; 
  width: 300px;

}

p {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 22px;
    margin-right: 360px;
    right: 100px;
}

.dropcap {
    float: left;
    font-size: 76px;
    line-height: 76px;
    margin: 0 15px 5px 0;
}

.section {
    background-color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}

    .section-header {
        margin-top: 50px
         !important;
        z-index: 1;
    }

.section-header-content {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 400px;
        left: 200px;
        color: white;
    }

.main-title {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 400px;
        left: 200px;
        color: white;
    }

.section-header-content2 {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 50px;
        left: 200px;
        color: white;
    }

.main-title2 {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 400px;
        right: 200px;
        color: white;
    }




    .section-video-bg {
        margin-top: -10px;
    }

.content {
    padding: 40px 0 25 ;

}

    .content h3 {
        font-size: 27px;
        line-height: 27px;
        margin: 70px 0 30px 0;
    }

    .content .content-media {
        width: 40%;
        border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
        padding: 30px 0;
    }

    .content .content-media.right {
        float: right;
        margin-left: 20px; 
    }

.content .content-media.left {
        float: right;
        margin-right: 800px; 
        bottom: 600px;
    }

    .content .content-media img {
        max-width: 100%;
    }

.column {
       float: left;
       width: 50%;
}

.video-container {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #000;
}

.video-container video {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.video-container video.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    z-index: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.video-container video.fillWidth {
    width: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;
}

/* Responsive: Portrait tablets and up */
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the following two styles on both divs? `float:left` and `display:inline-block`

Comment: What's up with that CSS randomly at the bottom? You haven't got that in your actual page have you? Vertically parallel or horizontally?

Answer (score 2):

You have a lot of stray divs on your html as well as a lot of css properties not needed (e.g. float property) which are already done by bootstrap's default css.

Here is the correct way to nest your div columns within a row:

```
<section class="section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="wrapper">   
                        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>    
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <p>Lorem Ipsum <em>Lorem</em>, Lorem impsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Here is a jsfiddle with the above code: http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/623ftfc2/

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is not properly formatted

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-6">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-6">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j0m6ddpo/1/